# Post-build event can't be executed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6, post-build-event

I've converted an old Visual C++ 6.0 project to a new Visual C++ 2010 one. It functions but I have a problem with the post build event which I took from the old project. It registered the target file (an .ocx) on the computer:

```
copy $(ProjDir)\PDFXChange\dll.Debug\*.* $(TargetDir) 
regsvr32 /s /c "$(TargetPath)" 
echo regsvr32 exec. time > "$(OutDir)\regsvr32.trg"
```

In my new solution it doesn't work. I've also tested it in single commands: of the three commands (copy, regsvr32 and echo) only the last one could be executed. What could be my error.

Error:

```
error MSB3073: The command "copy \PDFXChange\dll.Debug\*.* C:\_tests_\ocx2010\Debug\ 
regsvr32 /s /c "C:\_tests_\ocx2010\.\Debug\LayoutBox.dll" 
echo regsvr32 exec. time > ".\Debug\\regsvr32.trg"
:VCEnd" exited with code 3. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
```

COPY and REGSVR32 seem not to work.

Comment: What part doesn't work? What "error" do you get?

Comment: @Cody Gray    I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the name of the macro $(ProjDir). In Visual C++ 2010 it's $(ProjectDir)

$(ProjDir)   ->   $(Proj **ect** Dir)

Some macros altered their names (after so many years)!

The command **copy \PDFXChange\dll.Debug*.* C:*tests*\ocx2010\Debug** should copy some DLLs into the folder where the next command **regsvr32 /s /c "C:*tests*\ocx2010.\Debug\LayoutBox.dll** tried to register the target file. It couldn't find any DLLs there, so it quit with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch between
Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Output Directory
and
Project->Properties->Configuration->Linker->Output File

I made the former like so...
$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformTarget)$(Configuration)\

and in the linker like so..
$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformTarget)$(Configuration)$(ProjectName).dll

and it solved the problem